# What are the semantics of _internal?

Tags: dart

I keep seeing references to _internal in examples like the following:

```dart
class Symbol {
    final String name;
    static Map<String, Symbol> _cache;

    factory Symbol(String name) {
        if (_cache == null) {
        _cache = {};
     }

     if (_cache.containsKey(name)) {
        return _cache[name];
     } else {
        final symbol = new Symbol._internal(name);
        _cache[name] = symbol;
        return symbol;
      }
    }

  Symbol._internal(this.name);
}
```

I've gathered from the code that it's a privately accessible constructor.  The last line `Symbol._internal(this.name);` seems a bit confusing because it appears to be a statement within the class body and not within a method body, leading me to believe it's actually the internal constructor definition without a method body.

Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The **_internal** construction is just a name often given to constructors that are private to the class (the name is not required to be **._internal** you can create a private constructor using any **Class._someName** construction).

For example the following code only allows you to create new persons from outside the class using a caching constructor:

```dart
class Person {

    final String name;
    static Map<String,Person> _cache;

    factory Person(String name) {
        if(_cache === null) {
            _cache = new Map<String,Person>();
         }
         if(_cache[name] === null]) {
            _cache[name] = new Person._internal(name); 
         }
         return _cache[name];
    }
   
    Person._internal(this.name);
}
```

In general Dart treats any **_construction** as private to either the class or the library that contains it. For example you can define as a global function like this:

```dart
_globalToThisLibaryOnly() {
    print("can only be called globally within this #library");
}
```

which can be called from any file that is sourced within the library that defines it.

Comment: Thanks again, Lars.  This helps a lot.  There are still some things that I don't completely understand, like, constructors can optionally have a method body?  Class members defined as final can only be set within the list of parameters of the constructor, but not in the constructor body?  These are some of the things that still confuse me.

Comment: in addition to **Class._someName** it can also be **Class._**

Comment: Not from "outside", but from the inside. Typo there. Couldn't edit, due to "suggested edit queue is full" error on stackoverflow.