# Why must the _internal() be called in the class?

Tags: dart

Even though I am familiar with singleton, Dart's factory is confusing. I have seen an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112506/what-are-the-semantics-of-internal), but the only thing I got from the answer is that the name can be whatever identifier that starts with an _. Even though the person had asked why it should be called, the answer does not seem to be explaining that.

If I comment out the `Dog._internal();` line, I get `Method not found: 'Dog._internal'.` It looks like calling a method, but is it like C's function prototype? But it has no return type. Can someone explain the `Dog._internal();` line to me?

```
class Dog
{
  static final Dog dog = Dog._internal();
  //Dog._internal();
  factory Dog()
  {
    return dog;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple concepts going on so lets go through the example:

```
  factory Dog()
  {
    return dog;
  }
```

This defines a [factory constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors). Factory constructors are much like normal static methods but must always return an object which are compatible with the type of which the factory constructor is part of. In our example the factory constructor must return a `Dog` object.

It is not a constructor in that sense that we already have created a object when we enter this method. Again, it can be compared to `static Dog Dog()` but is allowed to override the default constructor. So we must create the object manually and return it.

This allows us to control the behavior of when objects are created and in our case allows us to have a singleton pattern so when somebody are trying to create an instance of `Dog` they will always get the same object.

```
  Dog._internal();
```

This is called a [named constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors). Constructors in Dart can have given names which makes it easier to distinguish different constructors. But also because Dart does not allows us to override methods with different number of parameters.

Also, because of the name starting with `_` it means this constructor is marked private and cannot be used outside of the library it is part of. So if your code is part of a library, the code importing your library are not allowed to call your private constructor.

This is again a nifty trick to allow us to make a singleton since we don't want other than our own code to create a new instance (which are the only instance we want to create).

```
  static final Dog dog = Dog._internal();
```

This is essential creating the singleton. The reason for this is that `static` variables in Dart are [lazy-evaluated](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods) so the value `dog` does not really have any value before it is called. After first call, the value are "cached" so `Dog._internal(7)` are only called once as long our application (or more specific, our isoleate instance) are running.

I would properly call the variable `_instance` or `_dog` so it is also private.

Answer (score 2):

At class scope, `Dog._internal();` defines a [*named* constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors) named `_internal` that takes no arguments and has no body.  It's equivalent to `Dog._internal() {}`. This would be more obvious if the constructor took arguments and did work, for example:

```dart
class Dog {
  static final Dog dog = Dog._internal(7);

  Dog._internal(this.years) {
    registerAnimal(this);
  }

  factory Dog() {
    return dog;
  }

  int years;
}
```